# Concatenate multiple tiff images into single one page tiff image

Tags: command-line, 16.04, libtiff

I would like to combine multiple tiff images into a single one page tiff image preferably using some command line utility.

There is `tiffcp` utility. Although it combines the images quite well and, preserves the image quality and compression settings; it creates multiple pages.

Comment: Install and try `imagemagick`. Browse the internet for tutorials, for example http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/

Comment: There is significant quality loss with `imagemagick` for .tiff files and compression options like LZW in `tiffcp` are not available there.

Comment: Would it be an option to convert the images to another format without losing too much quality and after that create the collage (combo picture)?

Answer (score 0):

`feh` has a index & montage modes, where it reads multiple images and displays or creates a single image containing a grid of thumbnails with all the images.

The man page has this example:

```
 feh -irFarial/14 -O index.jpg /opt/images
         Make an index print of /opt/images and all directories
         below it, using 14 point Arial to write the image info
         under each thumbnail.  Save the image as index.jpg and
         don't display it, just exit. Note that this even works
         without a running X server
```

If you've got libreoffice installed you could try these:

```
feh -i -O index.jpg /usr/lib/libreoffice/share/gallery/www-back/
```

That creates an index with names of all the files. Or the following will open feh viewing the thumbnail image, but with no names:

```
feh  -m /usr/lib/libreoffice/share/gallery/www-back/
```